# Angular record the order of checkboxes as clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am trying to add the functionality in my angular application to record the order of the checkboxes as they are clicked and hence show them in same order as they were clicked.

Here is the snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('checkbox', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.array = [1, 5];
    $scope.array_ = angular.copy($scope.array);
    $scope.list = [{
        "id": 1,
            "value": "apple",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "value": "orange",
    }, {
        "id": 5,
            "value": "pear"
    }];

    $scope.update = function () {
        if ($scope.array.toString() !== $scope.array_.toString()) {
            return "Changed";
        } else {
            return "Not Changed";
        }
    };

})
});
```

In this snippet array should show the numbers in the order they were clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood exactly what you need but please check this **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBi7f9B0Oal5KKM8uLVo?p=preview)**

The idea is to use a function like this to record the click order:

```
$scope.onClick = function(box) {
  var index = $scope.model.clickOrder.indexOf(box);
  if (index !== -1) {
    $scope.model.clickOrder.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    $scope.model.clickOrder.push(box);
  }
  updateOrderedList();
};
```

And a function like this to update the checkboxes order:

```
var updateOrderedList = function() {
  $scope.model.orderedList = []
    .concat($scope.model.clickOrder)
    .concat($scope.model.list.filter(function(item) {
      return $scope.model.clickOrder.indexOf(item) === -1;
    }));
};
```